# Tempory column with increment number of row of union of two table

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have two tables:

```
hair_product_table  22 products
mix_product_tables  300 products table
```

Sample data:

```
select version() as 'mysql version';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hair_product_table`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hair_product_table` (
  `idphair` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productname` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `pic` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idphair`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mix_product_tables`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mix_product_tables` (
  `idmix` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productname` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `pic` text,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmix`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2776 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#insert dadata for hair_product_table

INSERT INTO `hair_product_table` (`idphair`, `productname`, `description`, `pic`) VALUES
(4, 'jselwe','',''),
(5, 'ddd','',''),
(6, 'jselwe','',''),
(7, 'jelwe','',''),
(8, 'jelwe','',''),
(9, 'jelwe','',''),
(10, 'jelwe','',''),
(11, 'jelwe','',''),
(12, 'jelwe','',''),
(13, 'jelwe','',''),
(14, 'jelwe','',''),
(15, 'jelwe','',''),
(16, 'jelwe','',''),
(17, 'jelwe','',''),
(18, 'jelwe','',''),
(19, 'jelwe','',''),
(20, 'jelwe','',''),
(21, 'jelwe','',''),
(22, 'jelwe','',''),
(23, 'jelwe','',''),
(24, 'jelwe','',''),
(25, 'jelwe','',''),
(26, 'jelwe','',''),
(27, 'jelwe','','');


#insert dadata for mix_product_tables


INSERT INTO `mix_product_tables` (`idmix`, `productname`, `description`, `pic`) VALUES
(1, 'mix1','',''),
(2, 'mix2','',''),
(3, 'mix3','',''),
(4, 'mix4','',''),
(5, 'mix5','',''),
(6, 'jselwe','',''),
(7, 'jelwe','',''),
(8, 'jelwe','',''),
(9, 'jelwe','',''),
(10, 'jelwe','',''),
(11, 'jelwe','',''),
(12, 'jelwe','',''),
(13, 'jelwe','',''),
(14, 'jelwe','',''),
(15, 'jelwe','',''),
(16, 'jelwe','',''),
(17, 'jelwe','',''),
(18, 'jelwe','',''),
(19, 'jelwe','',''),
(20, 'jelwe','',''),
(21, 'jelwe','',''),
(22, 'jelwe','',''),
(23, 'jelwe','',''),
(24, 'jelwe','',''),
(25, 'jelwe','',''),
(26, 'jelwe','',''),
(27, 'jelwe','',''),
(28, 'jselwe','',''),
(29, 'ddd','',''),
(30, 'ddd','',''),
(31, 'jselwe','',''),
(32, 'ddd','',''),
(33, 'jselwe','',''),
(34, 'jelwe','',''),
(35, 'jelwe','',''),
(36, 'jelwe','',''),
(37, 'jelwe','',''),
(38, 'jelwe','',''),
(39, 'jelwe','',''),
(40, 'jelwe','',''),
(41, 'jelwe','',''),
(42, 'jelwe','',''),
(43, 'jelwe','',''),
(44, 'jelwe','',''),
(45, 'jelwe','',''),
(46, 'jelwe','',''),
(47, 'jelwe','',''),
(48, 'jelwe','',''),
(49, 'jelwe','',''),
(50, 'jelwe','',''),
(51, 'jelwe','',''),
(52, 'jelwe','',''),
(53, 'jelwe','',''),
(54, 'jelwe','',''),
(55, 'jselwe','',''),
(56, 'ddd','',''),
(57, 'ddd','',''),
(58, 'jselwe','',''),
(59, 'ddd','',''),
(60, 'jselwe','',''),
(61, 'jelwe','',''),
(62, 'jelwe','',''),
(63, 'jelwe','',''),
(64, 'jelwe','',''),
(65, 'jelwe','',''),
(66, 'jelwe','',''),
(67, 'jelwe','',''),
(68, 'jelwe','',''),
(69, 'jelwe','',''),
(70, 'jelwe','',''),
(71, 'jelwe','',''),
(72, 'jelwe','',''),
(73, 'jelwe','',''),
(74, 'jelwe','',''),
(75, 'jelwe','',''),
(76, 'jelwe','',''),
(77, 'jelwe','',''),
(78, 'jelwe','',''),
(79, 'jelwe','',''),
(80, 'jelwe','',''),
(81, 'jelwe','',''),
(82, 'jselwe','',''),
(83, 'ddd','',''),
(84, 'ddd','',''),
(85, 'jselwe','',''),
(86, 'ddd','',''),
(87, 'jselwe','',''),
(88, 'jelwe','',''),
(89, 'jelwe','',''),
(90, 'jelwe','',''),
(91, 'jelwe','',''),
(92, 'jelwe','',''),
(93, 'jelwe','',''),
(94, 'jelwe','',''),
(95, 'jelwe','',''),
(96, 'jelwe','',''),
(97, 'jelwe','',''),
(98, 'jelwe','',''),
(99, 'jelwe','',''),
(100, 'jelwe','',''),
(101, 'jelwe','',''),
(102, 'jelwe','',''),
(103, 'jelwe','',''),
(104, 'jelwe','',''),
(105, 'jelwe','',''),
(106, 'jelwe','',''),
(107, 'jelwe','',''),
(108, 'jelwe','','');
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT  hpt.productname,  hpt.description, hpt.pic, hpt.idphair 
FROM  hair_product_table hpt
INNER JOIN mix_product_tables AS mpt
UNION SELECT mpt.productname,  mpt.description, mpt.pic, mpt.idmix 
FROM mix_product_tables AS mpt limit 30;
+-------------+-------------+------+---------+
| productname | description | pic  | idphair |
+-------------+-------------+------+---------+
| jselwe      |             |      |       4 |
| ddd         |             |      |       5 |
| jselwe      |             |      |       6 |
| jelwe       |             |      |       7 |
| jelwe       |             |      |       8 |
| jelwe       |             |      |       9 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      10 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      11 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      12 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      13 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      14 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      15 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      16 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      17 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      18 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      19 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      20 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      21 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      22 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      23 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      24 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      25 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      26 |
| jelwe       |             |      |      27 |
| mix1        |             |      |       1 |
| mix2        |             |      |       2 |
| mix3        |             |      |       3 |
| mix4        |             |      |       4 |
| mix5        |             |      |       5 |
| jselwe      |             |      |      28 |
+-------------+-------------+------+---------+
```

And rextest of same: http://rextester.com/edit/KTAR73194

For display all products, I don't have problem

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,'SELECT  hpt.productname,  hpt.description, hpt.pic, hpt.idphair 
FROM  hair_product_table hpt
INNER JOIN mix_product_tables AS mpt
UNION SELECT mpt.productname,  mpt.description, mpt.pic, mpt.idmix 
FROM mix_product_tables AS mpt limit 30');
```

Now  I want to show a link more product

I make a new  page m**ore_product_page.php**.

With Ajax when i click on this link

`<div id="show_more_product<?php echo $last_id_product ?>" title="Load more product">More product</div>` to access to this page I send the left id 
this is there that i have a problem,  $last_id_product take take the last id   "id:8" instead the last id union "id:30" from last product of table mix_product_table

My question is how to have the exact id for the union table or if i can create a tempory column like a rowNumber for the 2 tables  start from 1 to 30

Thanks

Comment: Can you please re-read your question and make it clearer, I'm having a hard time following what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have a temporary column with incrementation which gives me the number of row displayed. That is 1 to 30. Because I would need the value of 30 to send it by Ajax on the other page that will start a query on the same temporary column this time greater than 30 so 31 a 60 so on. The solution is either that I find the id of exact row or I create a temporary column.

Comment: Your solution is over complicating the fact that `LIMIT` can take an offset, ie `LIMIT 30,10` would be "Get 10 records starting at the 30th offset.

Comment: I think so. That's why i think a temporary column can solve this problem. Except that I don't know how to create a tempory colum rowID that  takes the place of the id of the two tables.

Comment: I would like add that column  "(@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, "  but i don't know how.

Comment: hello @Strawberry I alreaty put it in rexterter or to show it here?  thanks

Comment: Well, we're not going to guess where it is!

Comment: @Strawberry this is here http://rextester.com/KTAR73194

Comment: I really don't understand what it is you're trying to do - or how hair products relate to mix products. Perhaps you have been consuming too much of your product.

Comment: hello @Strawberry thanks for update, i want to make a pagination with ajax with the button more product.  Everytime the users click on more button, it will show 30 products.  If i was 1 table only, it will good, i will use the id to see exactly what the last ID displayed to show the next 30 product.  The problem is I have two tables.  Now I can't display exactly the  30  in ascending order. For me the only solution is to create a tempory column "rownumber" by example to have the  order of row incremently.

Comment: But it's such a tiny data set. Just push the whole thing into memory (json, or whatever) and handle the pagination in your application code.

Comment: hello @StrawberryI have 37000 products mix, will not it be slow?

Comment: According to your question, you have 300 'mix products'. It might be slower to handle the  pagination in the application code - but I'd be tempted to try first before rejecting the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the core of your ridiculously overly-convoluted problem can be expressed as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;

CREATE TABLE a(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS b;

CREATE TABLE b(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

INSERT INTO b VALUES (3),(4),(5),(6),(7);

SELECT * FROM a UNION ALL SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY i;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
+----+
```

So now the two tables are jumbled up.

This can be easily resolved as follows.

```
SELECT 'a' source
     , id 
  FROM a 
 UNION 
SELECT 'b'
     , id
  FROM b 
 ORDER 
    BY source
     , id;
+--------+----+
| source | id |
+--------+----+
| a      |  1 |
| a      |  2 |
| a      |  3 |
| a      |  4 |
| a      |  5 |
| b      |  3 |
| b      |  4 |
| b      |  5 |
| b      |  6 |
| b      |  7 |
+--------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I have 2 questions:Is it a temporary table? Do I do this with each request? because I have to make a request each time I click on "Show more products".

Comment: No, it's not a temporary table. It's just the result of a query. You could do this with each request, but it's not how I would do it. Instead, I would just store the entire data set in a bit of json, and then use javascript for pagination. I'm no expert on pagination, but there are roughly half a billion tutorials and scripts out there. Here's one: http://pagination.js.org/

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, but i would like to have a good idea about the mysql before go for javascript.  The problem is that I have different name for Id in each table: idphair and idmix.  it's different of your sample.  how to resolve that.  Thanks

Comment: I think I've demonstrated how to ask a question in a clear and concise manner, omitting any and all extraneous details. I called my column 'source' and the values within it 'a' and 'b', but I could have chosen other values instead.

Comment: thanks for, but maybe I'm too bad, I can not get a distinct ID for the table union.

Comment: I really can't continue this discussion in comments. I suggest you either accept this answer delete this question. And then ask a new question - using a clearer, more concise sample data set (like my example above) or